# How do I detect an invalid auth token from chrome.identity.getAuthToken()?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The onInstall hook for my extension calls chrome.identity.getAuthToken(). If this is the first time I've run the app, all works OK.

The issue I have is that during testing, I am revoking access and then re-installing the extension. In this scenario, getAuthToken() is returning the cached, invalid token. Some time later, my extension is failing 401 when I try to use the extension. What I want to do is to detect that the extension has come from the cache, and immediately remove it so I can do the auth dialogue. If I could access the token expiration time, I could deduce its validity, but afaik, the expiration time isn't visible.

Any suggestions on how to code around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the utility classes, namely **[GDocs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/gdrive/js/gdocs.js)**, of **[GDrive App](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/angular_framework.html)** deals with it as follows:

1. Get a token (using **chrome.identity.getAuthToken()**).
2. Makes a request using that token.
3. If the request fails, clears it from cache (using **chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken()**) and requests a new one. (It allows for max. 1 retry, so it doesn't enter an infinite loop if the problem is other than token expiration.)

**The code:**

```
GDocs.prototype.upload = function (blob, callback, retry) {
  var onComplete = function (response) {...}.bind(this);
  var onError = function (response) {
    if (retry) {
      // `removeCachedAuthToekn()` uses `chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken()`
      // to remove the token from cache and then requests a new one using
      // `chrome.identity.getAuthToken()`. Finally, it calls `upload()` again
      // passing the `retry` parameter with value `false` */
      this.removeCachedAuthToken(...);
    } else {
      // The failure is permanent...
    }
  }.bind(this);
...

uploader = ...
...
uploader.upload();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had thought of that, so perhaps I should have added in my question "without actually trying to use it". I'll see if any other suggestions crop up before accepting this as the only option. Thanks again